# How can I compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2+4x+3}$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^3-2x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've checked out both of these functions at the points, where I have to compute the limits of the functions. I assume that  $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2+4x+3}$ does not exist, but how can I compute it? How can I compute the one-side limit of the second function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that $$\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+3)(x+1)}$$
and write $$\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2(x-2)}$$
Can you finish?
for the second example we get $$-\infty$$

Comment: $\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+3)(x+1)}$ if I substitute $x=-1$ than I get $\frac{(-1+2)(-1+1)}{(-1+3)(-1+1)}$ so it will be $0$?

Comment: no the limit means tends to $-1$ not equal to $-1$!

Comment: for the first limit we get $$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For what concerns the second one, since the first one has already been solved by Dr. Sonnhard G., you simply notice that

$$\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^3-2x^2} = \frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{x^2(x-2)}$$

Now you can simplify the identical terms to get

$$\frac{x-1}{x^2}$$

Hence the second one goes to $-\infty$